# CSS: variable font-size depending on text length

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make the font-size parameter depend on the length of the text?
Of course I could realize this is possible with JavaScript, but I don't want to. ;)

I have a box which has 140px width and height. The content should be 100px w+h (padding of the box: 20px). My text should use this 100px width best. Also on a text change on the page (AJAX) the text should assign to width=100px.

Is that possible?

Comment: It's not possible

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. Text length !== container width.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the length of the text in advance then you can set up media queries based on the screen size in your CSS to tailor the font-size accordingly.

```
@media (max-width: 367px) {
  .myContainer {
    font-size: 8px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 368px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .myContainer {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .myContainer {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

If you are dynamically generating the text with a server-side technology you should be able to see your text length and set an appropriate class to size the font:

```
// Example pseudo-code to illustrate the point...
int len = myText.length();
if (len > 2000) {
  setOutputClass("smallestSize");
} else if (len > 1000 && len < 2000) {
  setOutputClass("mediumSize");
} else {
  setOutputClass("largestSize");
}
```

And with that corresponding class rules in your CSS:

```
.smallestSize {
  font-size: 8px;
}

.mediumSize {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.largestSize {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

I'm pretty sure there is no way to determine the length of text within CSS, so ultimately you may be forced to use JavaScript or approach the solution a bit differently.